# Absolute value counter example

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Give a counterexample, if possible, to this universally quantified statements, where the domain for all variables consists of all integers.  $∀x(|x|>0)$.

I think the counterexample is as simple as $∀x(-|x|>0)$ but i am having doubts. What am i missing?

Comment: 0 is an integer...

Comment: Counterexample would be value of $x$ for which the statement under quantifier is false.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the word *counterexample* for *converse* or *negation*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a counter example for a statement that starts with "For all," you only need one object for which the statement does not hold. In this case, that object is 0. Since $|0|=0$ and $0$ is an integer, the statement "$\forall \text{ integer } x: |x|>0$" is wrong.

Comment: so i cannot provide a counterexample of it?

Comment: Yes you can. That counterexample is 0, which proves that the statement is wrong.

Comment: so if $x = 0$ is a sufficient enough counter example?

Comment: Yes. This is like me saying "all horses are black". And you showing me as a counter example a brown horse. In this analogy the brown horse is like $x=0$.

Comment: Also, could i give a domain for the variables for which each universally quantified statement is true?

Comment: The only domain for which each and every universally quantified statement is true is the empty domain. But for particular statements you may be able to find nontrivial domains. For example, if you change your domain for the statement in your question to *natural numbers*, then the statement is true.

Comment: @dirkgentley i typed that wrong     i meant  "Also, could i give a domain for the variables for which the universally quantified statement is true?

Answer (score 1):

$$0                 $$
is a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

| $0$ |   $\not\gt 0 $, so $0$ is your counterexample.